# Add columns to a CSV file from existing CSV files

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have multiple different csv files that each represent a single feature. I need to create a new csv file that takes each of these individual files and maps them to a new column in the new file.

I have tried something like this:

```
import csv

file = open("House_2_X.csv", 'a')

writer = csv.writer(file)
with open("House_2_TS copy/channel_1(TimeStamp).csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        
        with open("House_2_BOTH copy/channel_2(BOTH).csv", 'r') as f1:
            for line1 in f1:
                a = line1[12:]
                line1 = a[:4]
                writer.writerow([line, line1])

                                                                                                     
file.close()
```

but this does not work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How it does not work?

Comment: @Dimitry the datasets are huge so I haven't actually let it run all the way. It would take too long.

Comment: @dus does my edited response help you with large files?

Comment: @suvayu It helped with larger files. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use `pandas`.  Since you did not show an example file, assuming each file has a single column, something like this could work.

```
cols = [pd.read_csv(f, squeeze=True) for f in file_paths]
df = pd.concat([cols], axis=1)
df.to_csv("newfile.csv")
```

**EDIT:**

Since there has been a comment about large files, here's an approach with `dask`.

With 3 CSVs that look like this:

```
$ for f in *.csv; do cat $f; echo; done
abc
def
ghi

ABC
DEF
GHI

a_b_c
d_e_f
g_h_i
```

The following:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv("*.csv", header=None).squeeze()
df = dd.concat(list(df.partitions), axis=1) # see note below
df.compute() # this should return you to pandas
```

Gives me this:

```
     0    0      0
0  abc  ABC  a_b_c
1  def  DEF  d_e_f
2  ghi  GHI  g_h_i
```

You can scale this to a cluster.  However, if you cannot deploy a cluster, I will repeat my comment below, you should look at a solution using Apache Arrow.

*NOTE:* the `concat` step will generate a `UserWarning`.  To make sure you can ignore it, you have to do some ground work and ensure all your CSVs align (as in, same number of rows.  If that's not the case, you need to pre-process them before merging.

Any help related to either the pre-processing or the Arrow should be separate questions.

**EDIT2:**

Here's an alternate pandas based approach more amenable to large files:

```
chunked_readers = [
    pd.read_csv(f, chunksize=<size>, header=None, squeeze=True)
    for f in file_paths
]
for i, dfs in enumerate(zip(*chunked_readers):
    df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
    df.to_csv(f"merged_{i}.csv")
```

Choose the `chunksize` as per your resource constraints.  To be sure not to run out of memory, you could also call `gc.collect()` within the loop.

Comment: Not a bad idea if your data is small.  Pandas is outrageously memory-hungry for such a simple operation.  Try doing your operation on a 50GB file.

Comment: @TomServo - Sadly that's true. A lot of times we also store in pandas dataframes a lot of data as 'str' or 'object', which also hurts performance.  IMHO pandas.read_csv() has some treasures like the `true_values` and `false_values` arguments that aleviates converting some columns by hand and reduces memory consumption.

Comment: @TomServo The OP didn't mention anything about large files in the main question, but now I see there's a comment.  If that's important, I would recommend using Apache Arrow.  Also, if memory usage of string types is important to you, you should look at the [latest release of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#pyarrow-backed-string-data-type).

Comment: @TomServo I made some edits addressing large files.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky to say more without knowing the shape of the data but this will work if the column name in every csv is different, which I think it should be since you said they all have different features.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

csvs = glob.glob('path_to_folder_containing_all_your_csvs/*.csv')

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(s) for s in csvs))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the example is slow because you keep opening and closing (and reading from disk) the same file inside the loop. It should probably be:

```
with open("House_2_TS copy/channel_1(TimeStamp).csv") as f, open("House_2_BOTH copy/channel_2(BOTH).csv", 'r') as f1:
for line in f:
     for line1 in f1:
          line1  = line1[12:16]
          writer.writerow([line, line1])
     f1.seek(0)
```

That is if you want the new file to have `len(f) * len(f1)` lines. You could also store the second file lines in a list if it fits in memory to speed up the loop.

If you didn't mean to nest loops, then the code is

```
with open("House_2_TS copy/channel_1(TimeStamp).csv") as f, open("House_2_BOTH copy/channel_2(BOTH).csv", 'r') as f1:
for line,line1 in zip(f,f1):
    line1  = line1[12:16]
    writer.writerow([line, line1])
```